# How to setup HAProxy to drop connection on matching query string key value?

Tags: linux, centos7, haproxy

I have installed HAProxy 1.5.18 on a Centos 7.

In the `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg` I have following line:

```
frontend free_api
        bind *:80
        stats uri /haproxy?stats
        mode http
        option forwardfor         
        acl key1 urlp(key) 12345
        acl key2 urlp(key) 6789

        http-request deny if key1
        http-request deny if key2

       # use_backend api if api
 default_backend api
```

Right now the URL access gets denied for query string key with a matching value of **12345** or **6789**. HAProxy returns a `403 Forbidden` status code back.

What I am looking is to simply drop the connection so nothing is returned back to user? How to do that in HAProxy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use haproxy v1.6 and higher, and directive `silent-drop`

```
http-request silent-drop if key1
```

> "silent-drop" : this stops the evaluation of the rules and makes the
>       client-facing connection suddenly disappear using a system-dependent way
>       that tries to prevent the client from being notified. The effect it then
>       that the client still sees an established connection while there's none
>       on HAProxy. The purpose is to achieve a comparable effect to "tarpit"
>       except that it doesn't use any local resource at all on the machine
>       running HAProxy. It can resist much higher loads than "tarpit", and slow
>       down stronger attackers. It is important to understand the impact of using
>       this mechanism. All stateful equipment placed between the client and
>       HAProxy (firewalls, proxies, load balancers) will also keep the
>       established connection for a long time and may suffer from this action.
>       On modern Linux systems running with enough privileges, the TCP_REPAIR
>       socket option is used to block the emission of a TCP reset. On other
>       systems, the socket's TTL is reduced to 1 so that the TCP reset doesn't
>       pass the first router, though it's still delivered to local networks. Do
>       not use it unless you fully understand how it works.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: The down-voter should explain.  This answer is correct.